# Circular scale animation

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, material-design

I'm trying to achieve an animation which scales over a view like this:

[image: Curved animation]

At the moment I'm using a scale animation loaded from xml:

This in action looks like this:

[image: Square like scale animation]

It scales more like a square.

I was using ObjectAnimator/ValueAnimator with properties before.

Some devices had specific problems with measuring heights for scaling so I reverted to using xml definitions.

Does anyone have any clue how to achieve the above?

Answer (score 2):

you must define programmatically you `ScaleAnimation`.

first get radius of your circle(`ImageView`) at first position(before start `Animation`).
for get radius you can get width of your `imageview` and then division to 2.

second you must get width and height of your square.

third do it : 
 `anim_to = (width_square + height_Square) / radius_circle;`

finally set "anim_to" to your ScaleAnimation and start animation like this:

```
ScaleAnimation my_reveal = new ScaleAnimation(1,anim_to, 1,anim_to, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
my_reveal.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
my_reveal.setDuration(500);
my_circle.startAnimation(my_reveal);
```

sorry for my bad ENG ;)